# How to add a class to dropdown window when content is now visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I recently put together a dropdown window with hidden content and once clicked, it will show the content behind it then add a hash to the anchor of the url so that if the link is copied and sent to someone else. Once the link is opened it will automatically open the dropdown that was selected.

Here is my code...

HTML

```
<div class="dropdown_wrapper">
   <a href="#!window1" id="window1" class="dropdown">Title 1</a>
   <div class="hidden dropdown_content">
      <p>Hidden Content for window 1</p>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown_wrapper">
   <a href="#!window2" id="window2" class="dropdown">Title 2</a>
   <div class="hidden dropdown_content">
      <p>Hidden Content for window 2</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

jQuery that opens dropdown if it contains a particular hash

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var urlHash = window.location.hash.replace('#!', '');
    if (window.location.hash.indexOf('!') == 1 && $('.dropdown_wrapper').length > 0) {
        $('#' + urlHash).next('.dropdown_content').slideDown(300);
    }
});
```

jQuery for the actual onclick functionality to open dropdown

```
$('.dropdown').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).next('.dropdown_content').slideUp(300);
    }else{
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).next('.dropdown_content').slideDown(300);
    }
});
```

My question is, how do i get the active class that changes the button I have from a plus to a minus as if it was clicked, when someone goes directly to a url with the dropdown open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the icon swap implemented right?
Wouldn't it be as simple as that then?

```
 $('#' + urlHash).addClass('active')
```

in your $(document).ready() {}

P.S.: I'm not sure if I have understood your question completely. So just tell me if you meant it differently.

Comment: Can't believe I missed something so simple... Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Add the Image swap to the Css when active

```
.active {
      background-image:url("ulrto Plus Image Here") !important
 }
```

and on all the other Select Items change the css to

```
.DropDownMenuItem {
  background-image:url("ulr to Minus Image Here") 
}
```